# Remember Token error when using custom authentication in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am using custom authentication in Laravel 7 and have a `CustomAuthUser` class, which retunrs an instance of the `GenericUser`. Everything works fine, but there is an issue with the logout. I am using `Auth::logout()`, but it is showing me an error that

```
Undefined index: remember_token
```

As I use custom tables, I don't have `remember_token` filed in the database. The error is on `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/GenericUser.php:64` where it is calling `return $this->attributes[$this->getRememberTokenName()];`

I tried by adding the following method to the CustomAuthUser class but it is not working.

```
  public function updateRememberToken(UserContract $user, $token)
    {
    }
```

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Are you able to just add `remember_token` to the table?

Comment: still it is showing the same error. In fact, I don't use the table for authentication.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing remember_token to GenericUser constructor?

Comment: nope. That was the issue. I passed a dummy value for the index and it is working fine now. Thanks a lot !! . If you can make it as an answer, I will accept it .

Comment: I am glad that it worked ) I'll compile an answer, just in case someone need that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GenericUser` is expecting all it's attributes be passed in the constructor:

```php
    public function __construct(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
    }
```

And since `remember_token` not passed it will throw `Undefined index` error when trying to access it in:

```php
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->attributes[$this->getRememberTokenName()];
    }
```

Probably the easiest way is to add additional dummy `remember_token` element or override `getRememberToken` altogether...

Cheers ;)